# IIS URL Rewrite not passing params

Tags: iis

I want to rewrite a url from this:

```
blah.com/web/code=BSIL
```

to this:

```
blah.com/web/logon.html?app=BSIL&embed=true&installApp=false
```

It works with Redirect, but with Rewrite the params are not passed through.

I've tried working through examples using Conditions and Rewrite maps, but that got messy and I couldn't get it to work, so thought I'd should start from scratch to keep it simple.

Rules:

```
<rewrite>
    <globalRules>
        <rule name="test" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*web/code=BSIL" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/web/logon.html?app=BSIL&amp;embed=true&amp;installApp=false" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*web/code=EC" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/web/logon.html?app=EC&amp;embed=true&amp;installApp=false" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
    </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```

[Screen shot from Chrome using Redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJO6f.png)

[Screen shot from Chrome using Rewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSr1u.png)

Comment: You might refer to https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 1. If your goal is to rewrite, you don't need `*` in your match tag, and there is also no need to use `{R:1}/` in action tag. To troubleshoot with more details, learn FRT https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thanks Lex. I confirmed the params _are_ being passed through, but for some reason not getting processed by the html? Maybe some URI issue that I don't have time for.. So I've change tack and instead of one rule per client I've got one file per client that a single rewrite rule accommodates for nicely.